# Sufficient condition for self-concordance?

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, hessian-matrix

I've revised a previous question that was ill-formed. Consider the following two definitions.

> **Def'n 1** *(Lipschitz continuity of Hessian)*: A function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is said to have a Lipschitz continuous
>   Hessian if there exists $L>0$ such that $\|\nabla^2f(x) -
> > \nabla^2f(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$.
>
> **Def'n 2** *(Self-concordance)*: Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be a convex open set. Then $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is said to be
>   self-concordant with parameter $\sigma>0$ at $x\in\Omega$ if 
>   \begin{align} \nabla^2f(x)(h,h) \ge 0 \end{align} and \begin{align}
> [\nabla^3f(x)(h,h,h)]^2 \le 4\sigma(h^\top\nabla^2f(x)h)^3 \end{align}
>   for all $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$; $f$ is self-concordant on $\Omega$ if the
>   above two inequalities hold for all $x\in\Omega$.

**Note**: The term $\nabla^3f(x)(h,h,h)$ means $\sum_{i,j,k=1}^n\frac{\partial^3 f(x)}{\partial x_i\partial x_j\partial x_k}h_ih_jh_k$.

The condition for self-concordance of a function is quite difficult to check, motivating a search for an alternate or sufficient condition.

---

**My attempt**:

Consider a three times continuously differentiable function $f$ that is strongly convex and has a Lipschitz continuous Hessian. I imagine a condition that looks something like the following *may* be enough for self-concordance but I'm not sure if it makes sense:

> $f$ is self-concordant with parameter $\sigma>0$ if for all $x,y$
>   \begin{align}
> \|\nabla^2f(x)-\nabla^2f(y)\|\le2\sigma(h^\top\nabla^2f(x)h)^{3/2}
> \end{align} for all $h\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

That is, the Hessian of $f$ does not change too much (bounded by some function of the Hessian itself). Does anyone have any further insight?

Comment: the left hand side does not depend on $h$ ... so for $h=0$ you have that $\nabla^2 f$ is constant.

Comment: @user251257 Ah, yes. Do you see any way to state the self-concordance conditions just in terms of the Hessian? Perhaps $h$ should be related in some way to $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I think it is essential to bound the third derivative by the second. however whatever you try, try it first on $f(x) = -\log(x)$ :)